# Packaging common resource files between python and java projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I have a project that has been implemented in both Java and Python. Both implementations are stored in the same repository. Currently my directory structure looks like this:

```
mycoolthing/
|-templates/
   |-templateA.txt
   |-templateB.txt
   |-templateC.txt
|-java/
   |-src/
   |-pom.xml
   |-README.md
|-python/
   |-setup.py
   |-README.md
   |-mycoolthing/
     |-mycoolthing.py
   |-tests/
     |-mycoolthing_integration_test.py
```

Both the Python and the Java implementations rely on the set of template files that are in the `templates` directory. Ideally I want these files to only live in one place so I don't have to manage two sets of the same template files. These template files are used at runtime and will be updated from time to time, but the underlying python code that reading them in will rarely change.

I am not sure how to manage the scenario of resources that are outside the python project. Python allows me to load these files if I move the `templates` folder into the the `python` directory and add an `__init.py__` to the directory. I can then use `importlib_resources` to reference the files through `pkg_resources` like so:

```py
import importlib_resources as pkg_resources
text = pkg_resources.read_text('templates', 'templateA.txt')
```

The `mycoolthing_integration_test.py` file also needs to support importing the `mycoolthing` package which in turn needs to have access to the `templates` files. For example:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
from mycoolthing import widget
```

Where `widget` is a class within mycoolthing.py and reads the template file from `pkg_resources` like the example above. Again, this only works if the `templates` folder is within the python directory and includes the `__init.py__`.

I also want to be able to install the python package `mycoolthing` via `setup.py install` and include all of the template files in this installation. I am able to package the template data within the installation via the `package_data` property in `setup.py` if the templates directory lives within the python directory, but again my goal is to have all the templates live outside of the python package directory.

What is the best practice in python for managing shared resources with other projects for both local development and packaging via `setup.py`.

Answer (score 1):

A custom *setuptools* command might help...

Here is an example of a `setup.py` that copies the `../templates` directory into the built distribution. This is done by adding a custom `copy_templates` command as a sub-command of `install`.

```
import distutils.command.install
import os

import setuptools

class copy_templates(setuptools.Command):
    user_options = [
        ('install-dir=', 'd', "directory to install to"),
    ]
    def initialize_options(self):
        self.install_dir = None
    def finalize_options(self):
        self.set_undefined_options(
            'install', ('install_lib', 'install_dir'),
        )
    def run(self):
        self.copy_tree(
            '../templates',
            self.install_dir + 'mycoolthing/templates',
        )

class install(distutils.command.install.install):
    _sub_command = ('copy_templates', None,)
    _sub_commands = distutils.command.install.install.sub_commands
    sub_commands = [_sub_command] + _sub_commands

def setup():
    setuptools.setup(
        # see 'setup.cfg'
        cmdclass={
            'copy_templates': copy_templates,
            'install': install,
        },
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

There are of course some subtleties, that can probably be fixed, for example:

- the templates will be missing in an `sdist` as it doesn't run the `install` command.